# Concatenate array and string for CSV

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, concatenation

I'm attempting to concatenate a string to an array value. Since the URL/domain is the same, I simply store the users email prefix and append the url/domain.  I need to export the full email address out to CSV:

```
 CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    columns = %w(name, email_address) 
    url = "@example.com"   
    all.each do |location|
      csv << location.attributes.values_at(*columns) + [url]     
    end
  end
```

Currently the resulting output is:

```
Joe, user1, @example.com
Bob, user2, @example.com
```

What I need is:

```
Joe, user1@example.com
Bob, user2@example.com
```

How can I achieve the above?

Comment: `csv << [location.name, "#{location.email_address}@example.com"]` should work.

Comment: Hello, @Stefan. You've been [AWOL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/AWOL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location` is a model object, right?

```
CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
  domain = "example.com"

  all.each do |location|    
    csv << [location.name, "#{location.email_address}@#{domain}"]
  end
end
```

Update:

IMO that's cleaner as well. But if you want to keep your version, then I suggest you create a `full_email_address` method in your `Location` model which returns something like `username@domain.com`.

Then, you can vary the columns data later on and easily modify your CSV output. Like so:

```
class Location << ActiveRecord::Base
  def full_email_address
    return "" if self.email_address.blank?

    domain = "example.com" # or save this as a constant in the class
    "#{self.email_address}@#{domain}"
  end
end

CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
  columns = %w{name full_email_address} # add other methods or attributes here

  all.each do |location|
    csv << columns.map{ |moa| location.public_send(moa) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
  columns = %w(name, email_address) 
  url = "@example.com"   
  all.each do |location|
    row = location.attributes.values_at(*columns)
    row[-1] = row[-1] + url
    csv << row
  end
end
```

Currently the array written to CSV is `['Joe', 'user1'] + ['@example.com']`, so instead of adding `url` to the attributes array I am adding it to the last attribute.

Comment: `row[-1] += url` would be better

Comment: `row[-1] << url` would be even better.